# Apache 2.4.39 Win64 successful start

Tags: apache-http-server

After manipulating with different Windows Apache "localhost hosting" packs, I get such info when I try to launch Apache from `httpd-2.4.39-win64-VC15` from `C:\Apache24`:

```
C:\Apache24\bin>httpd.exe -k install
[Thu May 16 15:22:09.749331 2019] [mpm_winnt:error] [pid 6408:tid 416] AH00433: Apache2.4: Service is already installed.

C:\Apache24\bin>httpd.exe -k stop
(OS 5)???????? ? ???????.  : AH10014: Failed to open the 'Apache2.4' service
```

I try to search duplicates of `httpd.exe`, but I don't find duplicates.

*So how to understand such messages, as:  `Service is already installed.` and `Failed to open the 'Apache2.4' service` from when it started? And how to stop this server?*

I check this:

After edit `httpd.conf`

```
#ServerName www.example.com:80
```

to:

```
ServerName localhost
```

and

```
C:\Apache24\bin>httpd.exe -k start
```

I get page with "nothing" (not default `index.html` with **it works**)

Comment: But you’re not trying to launch it...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I install new latest Windows 10 install and new install of Apache and it works.